# Routing parameter with blazor server

Tags: c#, parameters, routes, blazor, blazor-server-side

```
@page "/customer"
@page "/customer/{id:int}"//work
@page "/customer/{BigId:Int64}"//not work



@code {

[Parameter]
public int? id { get; set; }//work

[Parameter]
public Int64? BigId { get; set; }//not work
}
```

> Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router.Refresh(Boolean isNavigationIntercepted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)

Comment: FYI `int64` doesn't exist in C#, `Int64` (notice the capital `I`) does. Plus, "not work" isn't and will never be a technical description of a problem. Why doesn't it work? Are you getting an error message? An exception?

Comment: I added more information

Comment: The code that throws the exception is still not there. A `NullReferenceException` happens when you access a variable that's null, like `BigId.ToString()` will throw if `BigId` is null. Furthermore, in C#, an `int` and `long` (`Int64`) have some overlap, so, have you tried with a number that's *not* and integer, but *is* a long? Something like `4294967294`

Comment: The project does not upload at all, the error is displayed immediately

Comment: For one thing, `Int64` is not a valid route parameter constraint. i.e. `{BigId:Int64}`.  `long` is the constraint to use instead.

Comment: Long does not work either. This seems to be something more general

Comment: The issue is the signature is basically the same. You need to change the route a little itself @page "/customer/something/{BigId:long}"/. Everything in the html world gets stringified.... Docs on parameters : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#route-constraints

Answer (score 0):

I refer you to the [Ms-Docs documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#route-constraints) on permitted constraints on routes.
[image]

An `Int64` is a `long`.

```
@page "/customer/{BigId:long}
```